# Mac Swift - How do I download an image and load it into a NSImageView?

Tags: swift, image, macos, nsimageview

I want to download an image from a URL and show it in my swift application for OSX. The solutions for iOS do not work for OSX.

I want the image to get downloaded and show it in a NSImageView.

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work for OSX"?

Comment: @qop Seeing the image adds no information. Let's avoid showing animated GIFs if they are not related to the issue at hand. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By simply:

```
let image = NSImage(byReferencingURL:NSURL(string: "http://theinterweb.net/ico/robotics_notes.gif")!)
let imageView = NSImageView()
imageView.image = image
```

You can get the [Playground Example here](https://github.com/x43x61x69/macOS-Image-From-URL), or in **Objective-C**:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theinterweb.net/ico/robotics_notes.gif"]];
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = image;
```

You can, of course, load the URL into **NSData** then convert to **NSImage** if you like, just like on iOS.